# ¿Por qué mi color de background de mi sidebar no funciona?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un elemento Sidebar que tiene una propiedad background pero no se ve. Sin embargo los div de columnas que están dentro del sidebar, sí respetan el background del mismo. Me gustaría que pudiera verse en el sidebar y no consigo hacerlo.
Dejo capturas del código html y CSS y también de la vista.
Muchas gracias.

```
<div id="sidebar">
            <div id="columna-izquierda">
                <h6>ultima semana</h6>
                <div class="contenedor-comentario">
                    <h3>comentario #1</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptiodaonsañn doaishoda idad</p>    
                </div>
                <div class="contenedor-comentario">
                    <h3>comentario #2</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptiodaonsañn doaishoda idad</p>    
                </div>
                <div class="contenedor-comentario">
                    <h3>comentario #3</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptiodaonsañn doaishoda idad</p>    
                </div>   
                <p>copyright carreras 2022</p>         
            <div id="columna-derecha">
                <p>proxima semana</p>
                <div class="fecha">
                    <p>29-07</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fecha">
                    <p>25-07</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fecha">
                    <p>20-07</p>
                </div>
                <div class="redes">
                    <p>Fb</p>
                    <p>Ig</p>
                    <p>Ln</p>
                    <p>Tw</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <span class="equis">
                <img id="cerrar" src="Exports/Iconos_Web_Carreras_Cruz.png" alt="">
            </span>
        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y el CSS:

Comment: y el CSS:

#sidebar {
    background: #0b0a0a;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1200px;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 740px;
    background: #0b0a0a;
}

Comment: Yo veo que el color #0b0a0a está puesto

Comment: el #0b0a0a está puesto dentro de cada div de columna, pero no en el contenedor que es el sidebar. De hecho, por fuera de las columnas se ve la imagen de abajo que no debería de verse

Comment: Agrega tu código CSS, de lo contrario no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Antonio, pensé que se había agregado, pero es evidente que no. Igualmente pude resolver el problema ya. Muchas gracias!